# Caesar cipher encrypting a single character in MIPS

Tags: assembly, encryption, mips, caesar-cipher

I'm having some problems in creating a program to encrypt a message. At this point i'm just trying to input a char and the output should be the char+5 positions in the alphabet.

So the program should read the char in ASCII and add 5 to it and then print the letter.  Ex.:

```
 Input: A
 Output: F
```

It should only work for Capital letters, so every char should be >=65 and <=90. So, if I write 'Z' it should start the alphabet from the beginning and print 'E'.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
    li $v0, 8               #read_string
    syscall                 #adresses char at $v0
    
    
    li $v0, 5               #char ASCII (I GUESS IT SHOULD)
    move $t0, $v0           #moves char(ASCII) to $t0
    li $s0, 90
    li $s1, 65
    bgt $t0, $s0, le_string # checks if char(ASCII) > 90
    ble $t0, $s1, le_string # checks if char(ASCII) < 65
    
        
    
    li $s0, 5               
    add $t1, $t1, $s0       #char=char+5
    move $t2, $t1           #moves encrypted char to $t2
    
    
    li $v0, 4               #print_string
    move $a0, $t2       
    syscall
```

LOG of actual output:

```
25/DEZ/2015:
INPUT: A
OUTPUT: A
```

Comment: What is your architecture?

Comment: I wonder if your usage of `syscall` to read the string is right.

Comment: Where is the (supposedly) label `le_string`?

Comment: Is everyone getting school [Caesar Cipher](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7rca_9vrJAhWIYyYKHc4HAcoQFggqMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCaesar_cipher&usg=AFQjCNH_wfzxbbBg2oz8I4mpBMHhSr-AXw&sig2=Gfl7MAYmrUdSqFzl4IIKmg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.eWE) assignments the last couple of weeks?

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm using MIPS
the le_string is before all the code I put here... sorry I forgot...

Comment: @zaph I guess... I already had to do it in C and it's pretty easy compared to ASM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MIPS, the code should be like this:

```
    .text
main:
    li $v0, 8                 # read_string
    la $a0, textbuf           # adresses of char at $a0
    li $a1, 2                 # length to read at $a1
    syscall

    la $t0, textbuf
    lb $v0, 0($t0)            # char ASCII (I GUESS IT SHOULD)
    move $t0, $v0             # moves char(ASCII) to $t0
    li $s0, 90
    li $s1, 65
    bgt $t0, $s0, le_string   # checks if char(ASCII) > 90
    nop                       # avoid instruction after branch begin executed even if jump is taken
    blt $t0, $s1, le_string   # checks if char(ASCII) < 65
    nop                       # avoid instruction after branch begin executed even if jump is taken

    li $s2, 5
    li $s3, 26
    add $t0, $t0, $s2         # char=char+5
    ble $t0, $s0, nowrap_char # checks if encrypted char <= 90
    nop                       # avoid instruction after branch begin executed even if jump is taken
    sub $t0, $t0, $s3         # wrap the char
nowrap_char:
le_string:
    move $t2, $t0             # moves encrypted char to $t2

    la $t0, textbuf
    li $v0, 4                 # print_string
    sb $t2, 0($t0)            # put the encrypted char
    la $a0, textbuf
    syscall

    li $v0, 10                # exit
    syscall

    .data
textbuf:
    .space 2
```

Comment: MARS and SPIM default to emulating a MIPS without branch-delay slots.  So people using that can remove the `nop`s from this code.

Comment: MIPS has add-immediate, you can `addiu $t0, $t0, 5` instead of wasting an instruction putting that constant 5 in a register. (However, MIPS doesn't have `bgt` between two registers, only against implicit zero like `bgez`; `bgt` is a pseudo instruction so you might as well use an immediate there as well. Or `slti` / `bne` if you want to do it manually.  (Or `addiu` with a negative number and compare the result against zero, since your inputs are narrow sign-extended so the subtraction can't overflow, making minus the same as less-than.)